# How to view a Gauge that is being measured by multiple instances in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, gauge

I've got a gauge to measure the number of unprocessed objects sitting in a queue. This queue is being polled by multiple instances, each of which records the size of the queue on each poll.

The problem is visualising this information using PromQL. I want to see the size of the gauge whenever it is measured, no matter which instance measured it.

If I just query the raw gauge metric I'll get a line on the graph for each instance. Is there any way to simply see the value of the gauge ignoring the instance label? I don't want to aggregate them or anything - since each instance is measuring the same thing.

Comment: Since different instances give Prometheus different data it's logical that you have multiple different timeseries. Why are you polling queue size from clients, and not the queue itself?

Comment: You can apply one of the aggregation functions, e.g. `min()`, `max()`, etc. I know you said you don't want this, but it's the easiest way.

Comment: @markalex in this case the "queue" is an email server. We don't own that, so the only way to measure the objects waiting on the server is using email server vendor's APIs.

Comment: @anemyte I think you're right. I've tried `max without (instance) (numberGauge)`, which looks roughly correct. I guess the different instances will be measuring the same value if they're running side by side, so it'll work. Thank you.

Comment: If you believe your instances always run, you also could select a single instance and show it's value at the dashboard.

Comment: @markalex not a bad suggestion. The challenge for me on that one is that each queue is polled independently. The polling requests are load balanced between multiple instances, and its only when polling that the size would be measured.

So an individual instance might not update its Gauge for several polling iterations, by which time its become stale.

Your first comment above makes me think that another approach for this would be to avoid measuring the queue sizes from the polling client, but have a completely separate app whose job is just to keep track of all the queue sizes.

Comment: Well, i believe separate application providing facade to metrics of you mail server is the most "kosher" way. But if you gather small number of metrics and your polling agents stable, using `max without (instance)` is justified. (And maybe even prefered)

Comment: @markalex the only downside I could see to using `max` is that if the queue size drops, then it needs to be polled by all of the instances before the prometheus query will reflect reality.

Comment: I'm not sure here, but `last_over_time(sum without (instance) (numberGauge[1h]))` could solve this. But depending on your polling situation you may also need to specify a resolution (like `[1h:1m]` or `[1h:30s]`)